# Why can't sbt find my local package

Tags: scala, sbt

Searching for examples of library use I downloaded this project.
https://github.com/marcusatbang/Hooks

I then moved the build.bat up one directory. Commented out the xsbt-gpg dependency lines in build.sbt and Build.scala since sbt couldn't find the package. I checked the source to comment out any imports of xsbt-gpg -- there were none. ( Surprise! )

So I managed to compile  the project. I then did `sbt publish-local`. `find ~/.ivy2 -iname "\*hooks*jar"` generated the following line: `.ivy2/local/cc.minotaur/hooks_2.9.0/0.1/jars/hooks_2.9.0.jar`.

I then entered the examples folder and tried to build the example project.
The build.scala contains the line: `libraryDependencies += "cc.minotaur" %% "hooks" % "0.1",` and it generates the error:  `unresolved dependency: cc.minotaur#hooks_2.9.1;0.1: not found`

So how do I fix this error? It seems to me it should be finding the hooks jar/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are using two versions of Scala. The one you are generating the jar is 2.9.0 while the one you are using in the example project is 2.9.1. Probably will solve the problem setting the same version in both projects.

Answer (score 0):

That could be that your [resolver](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html) doesn't see local directory. Try something like:

```
val ivyLocal = Resolver.file("local", file(Path.userHome.absolutePath +
   "/.ivy2/local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

externalResolvers += ivyLocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your scala version is 2.9.1, u have generated jar for version 2.9.0
change your library dependency as mentioned below.

```
libraryDependencies += "cc.minotaur" % "hooks_2.9.0" % "0.1"
```

or add `scalaVersion := "2.9.0"` in your `build.sbt` file